# Valgrind error invalid write/read of size 4 - doesn't find the problem after debugging - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, debugging, valgrind

Here is my code which implements Queue data structure using arrays in c. Pay attention the gMyQueue is a global variable of type Queue I have defined before. When running Valgrind on this program - it yells the error of invalid write and read of size 4. I have been debugging the code for a while, trying to catch the problem, scrutinizing the pointer addresses, values of indices, etc... But nothing seems to be wrong.

```
typedef struct Queue
{
    size_t numOfElems;
    size_t queueCapacity;
    int *data;
} Queue;

Queue gMyQueue;

void printQueue()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < gMyQueue.numOfElems; ++i)
    {
      printf("%d, ", gMyQueue.data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("numOfElems: %lu, queueCapacity: %lu\n",
           gMyQueue.numOfElems, gMyQueue.queueCapacity);
}

void cleanQueue()
{
    if (gMyQueue.data != NULL)
    {
        free(gMyQueue.data);
    }
}

void init()
{
    gMyQueue.data = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    gMyQueue.queueCapacity = 1;
    gMyQueue.numOfElems = 0;
}


void enqueue(int n) {
    if (gMyQueue.numOfElems == 0 && gMyQueue.data == NULL) {
        init();
        gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems] = n;
        gMyQueue.numOfElems++;
    }
    else {
        gMyQueue.numOfElems++;
        if (gMyQueue.numOfElems == gMyQueue.queueCapacity) {
            gMyQueue.queueCapacity *= 2;
            gMyQueue.data = (int*)realloc(gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity);
        }

        gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems - 1] = n;
    }
}

int dequeue(void) {
    int dequeue = 0;
    if (gMyQueue.numOfElems == 0) {
        return dequeue;;
    }
    else {
        dequeue = *(gMyQueue.data);
        for (int i = 0; i < gMyQueue.numOfElems - 1; i++)
        {
            gMyQueue.data[i] = gMyQueue.data[i + 1];
        }
        gMyQueue.numOfElems--;
    }
    return dequeue;
}
int main()
{
    init();
    enqueue(1);
    enqueue(2);
    dequeue();
    printQueue();
    cleanQueue();
    return 0;
}
```

I have been debugging it for a while, and it seems everything is okay, also with pointers and indices... but running valgrind yields that:

```
==12905== Invalid write of size 4
==12905==    at 0x108CC9: enqueue (main.c:200)
==12905==    by 0x109071: main (main.c:309)
==12905==  Address 0x522d090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==12905==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12905==    by 0x108CA5: enqueue (main.c:197)
==12905==    by 0x109071: main (main.c:309)
==12905== 
==12905== Invalid write of size 4
==12905==    at 0x108CC9: enqueue (main.c:200)
==12905==    by 0x10907B: main (main.c:310)
==12905==  Address 0x522d0e4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==12905==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12905==    by 0x108CA5: enqueue (main.c:197)
==12905==    by 0x10907B: main (main.c:310)
==12905== 
==12905== Invalid read of size 4
==12905==    at 0x108D2B: dequeue (main.c:213)
==12905==    by 0x109080: main (main.c:311)
==12905==  Address 0x522d0e4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==12905==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12905==    by 0x108CA5: enqueue (main.c:197)
==12905==    by 0x10907B: main (main.c:310)
```

Does someone know what's the matter?
Thank you.

Comment: Your `realloc()` doesn't look right: it looks at `queueCapacity` to allocate a number of *bytes* rather than a number of *int*.  Something like `realloc(gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity * sizeof(int));` seems in order.

Comment: The `cleanQueue()` function should reset the pointer to NULL and numbers to zero after freeing the data.  Otherwise, your code could mistakenly assume there is memory allocated when there is none.  If you never try to reuse the queue, it may not matter, but it's sensible to make sure things can't go wrong.

Comment: Also, you should show the reports from Valgrind from the code in the question.  I don't believe `enqueue()` is at line 200 in the code you show.  Identify the line numbers at a bare minimum (add comments to references line numbers — don't line number everything; we should be able to copy'n'paste your code and compile it).  See also the description of how to create MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Regarding the cleanQueue function - Do you mean I have to first iterate the queue - zeroing all the cell, and after the loop freeing the gMyQueue and assigning it with NULL? And I will take your remark into consideration, thank you!

Comment: No;  you need to set the three elements of the structure to zero, though.  You should use `void cleanQueue(void)
{
    if (gMyQueue.data != NULL)
    {
        free(gMyQueue.data); gMyQueue.data = NULL; gMyQueue.numElements = gMyQueue.queueCapacity = 0;
    }
}` . This ensures that things are dormant. when `enqueue()` is called again, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the thing I mentioned in my comment was the issue; you're not allocating enough memory in the `realloc() call`:

```
void enqueue(int n) {
    if (gMyQueue.numOfElems == 0 && gMyQueue.data == NULL) {
        init();
        gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems] = n;
        gMyQueue.numOfElems++;
    }
    else {
        gMyQueue.numOfElems++;
        if (gMyQueue.numOfElems == gMyQueue.queueCapacity) {
            gMyQueue.queueCapacity *= 2;
            gMyQueue.data = (int*)realloc(gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity); // HERE
        }

        gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems - 1] = n;
    }
}
```

Your code correctly extends the capacity - the max number of **items** - but during `realloc()` it doesn't convert **items** to **bytes**. You'd do that here:

```
gMyQueue.data = (int*)realloc(gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity * sizeof(int));
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, valgrind seems happy with it.

I recommend you actually derive the size from the variable rather than the name of the type.  Using `sizeof(* gMyQueue.data)` instead of `sizeof(int)` pulls the type from the thing that the variable points to, and it's one less then to have to change if you update your code.

For instance, if you wanted `data` to be an array of `long` rather than `int`, you of course have to update the structure to reflect the proper type, but you would not have to update the `sizeof`. Recommend doing the same in the original `malloc()` as well.

This is not required,  but it's a really good habit to get into and will avoid problems down the road.

Comment: You might want to mention not to cast the result of the `*alloc` family.

Answer (score 2):

At least the function `enqueue` is wrong.

The else statement shall not start with the increment of `numOfElems`

```
//...
else {
    gMyQueue.numOfElems++;
    //…
```

because this data member was already incremented in the first call of the function in the if statement

```
if (gMyQueue.numOfElems == 0 && gMyQueue.data == NULL) {
    init();
    gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems] = n;
    gMyQueue.numOfElems++;
}
```

This call of the function `realloc`

```
    gMyQueue.data = (int*)realloc(gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity);
```

is incorrect. The second argument shall specify the size of the newly allocated memory. So the call should look at least like

```
    gMyQueue.data = (int*)realloc(gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity * sizeof( int ) );
```

And you should to use an intermediate pointer because the function can return NULL. In this case, the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost.

The function can look like

```
void enqueue( int n ) 
{
    if ( gMyQueue.data == NULL ) 
    {
        init();
        gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems++] = n;
    }
    else 
    {
        if ( gMyQueue.numOfElems == gMyQueue.queueCapacity ) 
        {
            gMyQueue.queueCapacity *= 2;
            int *tmp = realloc( gMyQueue.data, gMyQueue.queueCapacity * sizeof( int ) );
            if ( tmp != NULL )
            {
                gMyQueue.data = tmp; 
                gMyQueue.data[gMyQueue.numOfElems++] = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But your implementation can terminate when the number of elements equals to the capacity which is considered wrong in our case. This is the reason I first incremented the number of elements, then compared... Thanks.

Comment: @HelpMe If the number of elements is equal tp the capacity then the memory is reallocated. I do not see whether it is terminated.

Comment: You are incrementing the number of elements after checking equality

Comment: @Helpme Investigate the code. Before incrementing the number of elements the memory is reallocated.